# SQL injection: real escape string function

Tags: web-application, sql-injection

**example4.php?id=id=2-1**

I came across the above injection and I can not figure out why(how) does this work and what's interesting is it returns all the records from the database.

Anything guys? educate me

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It runs the query `WHERE id=id`. As `id` is just another column and in SQL you can just pass name of column when doing comparison operations.

This is saying to fetch all rows WHERE `id` of the row equals `id` of the same row, which is true for all rows.

This is same as `WHERE 1=1`, it basically alters `WHERE` statement in such a way that it is always true.

Answer (score 1):

The injected fragment probably results in a query similar to this:

```
… WHERE id=id=2-1
```

Since MySQL is parsed from left to right, the above is equivalent to:

```
… WHERE (id=id)=2-1
```

So the expression `id=id` is evaluated first and returns [`1` (`TRUE` value)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html) for each row as any non-`NULL` value is equivalent to itself when using the [`=` operation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal). So it can be simplified to:

```
… WHERE 1=2-1
```

Which, oft course, can be simplified to:

```
… WHERE 1=1
```

And this, again, is true for each row with a non-`NULL` `id` value.

---

Regarding the title: it’s a [common misunderstanding that passing an input value through `mysql_real_escape_string` function makes it automatically safe to be used in an SQL statement](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/35718/539). Even the [PHP manual](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) states that ambiguous:

> This function must always (with few exceptions) be used to make data safe before sending a query to MySQL.

However, what the manual is missing is that values passed through `mysql_real_escape_string` are only supposed to be used in [MySQL string literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-literals.html) and nowhere else. Unfortunately, the manual misses to clarify that important aspect.

The result is that `mysql_real_escape_string` is also used for data which is not intended as a string literal. Like as a different [literal value](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/literals.html), a [keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html), or even as a [column or table identifier](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifiers.html).

Likewise, in the case discussed above, the input value is not used in a string literal, so `mysql_real_escape_string` won’t help. However, a prepared statement, in which the input would be passed as parameter, would have helped.